# How did Kamala do this in The Marvels?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel-2022, the-marvels

In the newly released *The Marvels*, towards the end of the movie, Kamala Khan

> uses her ability to make hard light (in the shape of a fist), but she is not wearing her bangle.

How does she do this? I thought that her powers were enabled

> only by her wearing her bangle, even though she may be a mutant or inhuman.

Or is there something that I am missing?

Note that Marvel reinterpreted her powers when moving from the comic book to live action, and I'm interested in a live action explanation.

Comment: I'm so glad you asked because I had the same question.

Comment: @Robbert Yeah, at the time I was "Wait ... ? WTF?"

Comment: I understand that it's considered that her inate powers were dormant until *activated* by the bangle.

Comment: The other question is where did the second bangle go, since she's only shown wearing one when she returns to Earth.

Comment: @jeffronicus: Speculation online is that SHIELD (or Captain Marvel) is holding onto it because they don't trust a teenager with the ability to open space-time portals. :-D

Comment: @jeffronicus I just watched the film. Capt. Marvel is wearing the other bangle in the end house-moving scene.

Comment: @Darren Ah, so now they are twinsies.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**The bangle is not the source of Kamala’s powers, but rather the catalyst that activated them.** She already had the innate potential for powers in her genes, as her friend [Bruno Carrelli](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Bruno_Carrelli), a scientific genius, explained. Bruno also implies that Kamala is a [mutant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_(Marvel_Comics)) (whose powers are innate and genetic).

Relevant dialogue/quotes:

> **Bruno:** So it looks like your power isn't coming from the bangle. It's coming from within you. Like the bangle unlocked the superhuman part of you.

- *Ms. Marvel* S01E02

> **Bruno:** So, I went back and looked at your genetic make-up again.
> […] when I compared you to the rest of your family, something still seemed off.
> Kamala, there's something different in your genes. Like... Like a mutation. [*"X-Men: The Animated Series" opening theme hook plays*]

- *Ms. Marvel* S01E06

[image: part of the Official Timeline quoted below]

> The bangle activates hidden powers in Kamala, however, allowing her to create blasts of solid crystalline energy that she calls "hard light."

> The mystical bangle unlocks hidden power within Kamala Khan.

- [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline)

[image: part of the Official Timeline quoted below]

> Kamala had previously learned from Bruno Carrelli's biometric scan that the bangle doesn't grant her power, it merely unlocked an ability that already existed within her.

- [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline)

[image: part of the Official Timeline quoted below]

> Kamala Khan has a genetic difference that leads to her powers.

- [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline)

Comment: _[Doobie-doobie-doooooooooooo doo-doo]_

Comment: Came here to point this out but didn't have episode references so good work.